# Trigger a journey based on data fields in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, landing-page, microsites

I have data fields City, Name of care center, Type of treatment, Email which we are going to capture from Microsite to get vote for best care center in city. A unique email id is associated with every vote.
On the back of this we'd like to trigger a journey based on this data fields. 
I am very new to SFMC. I don't know exactly how to set relationship and how can i do this. It may be silly question but I really need help on this..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from the Microsite are going to be stored in a Data Extension, correct?

If so, use that Data Extension as the Entry source for the Journey and based on the answers to these questions you can create Decision Split activities in the Journey.

[Journey Builder: Entry Events](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/)

How to set up journey from data extension:

1. Select Audience.
2. Then select Email Studio Audience
3. Add a name.
4. Select your Data Extension

Comment: Could you please explain how can i set up journey from data extension??  bcz in entry resources i have only Audience, API Event, Cloud pages, Salesforce data and Event

Comment: Select Audience. Then select Email Studio Audience. Add a name. Select your Data Extension.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will let  you know if i face any issue..!!!